# Hibernate Validator - @Length - How to specify separate message for min and max?

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate validator for form validation in my web-app. I am using the `@Length()` annotation for my String attribute as follows

```java
@Length(min = 5, message = "The field must be at least 5 characters")
private String myString;
```

However, I have a need to display a different message if the String exceeds 50 characters. Is there a way to use the out-of-the-box @Length validator to do this?  An example of what I would like to do (compiler will not let me) is as follows:

```
@Length(min = 5, message = "The field must be at least 5 characters")
@Length(max = 50, message = "The field must be less than 50 characters")
private String myString;
```

I have tried @Max and @Min and they do not do what I want.  Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can specify several `@Length` constraints at one element by using the inner [list annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.List.html) (which is defined for each constraint type in Bean Validation/Hibernate Validator) like this:

```
@List({
    @Length(min = 5, message = "The field must be at least 5 characters"),
    @Length(max = 50, message = "The field must be less than 50 characters")
})
private String myString;
```

Btw. I recommend to prefer [@Size](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/beanvalidation/api/index.html?javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) as defined by the Bean Validation API over `@Length` for portability reasons.

Comment: Note that as of Bean Validation 2.0 / Hibernate Validator 6, you'll be able to specify `@Length` and any other constraint multiple times, without the need for the explicit `@List` annotation.

Answer (score 16):

If you use the java standard javax.validation.constraint.Size, you can achieve the same thing this way:

```
@Size.List ({
    @Size(min=8, message="The field must be at least {min} characters"),
    @Size(max=60, message="The field must be less than {max} characters")
})
private String myString;
```

Notice that you can avoid hardcoding the field size by using message interpolation.

Answer (score 9):

According to documentation, you can use `@Length(min=, max=)`, with one message.  Then just change your message to "The field must be between 5 and 50 characters"

Comment: Yes, I like this solution, but unfortunately I have a requirement that must be implemented with separate messages.

Comment: You could create a custom constraint that would check both Min and Max and have separate messages for each: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html